# Do I need to convert audio files to .wav first before converting to .caf?

Tags: ios

I have several audio files which all of them are in .mp3 format. But playing .mp3 won't maximize the efficiency of audio playing on iOS. From [one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/233/audio-101-for-iphone-developers-converting-and-recording) of research, .wav or .caf is a go for short loop or sound effect audio file used in game. Thus I need to convert this .mp3 file into those two formats.

Currently I use the following command to convert .mp3 to .caf.

```
afconvert -f caff -d LEI16 kick_sfx.mp3
```

However, I see that .caf is a [container format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Audio_Format) thus I have a bad feeling that it's still not so efficient. According to that, I think I need to convert those .mp3 files to .wav first in order to maximize efficiency in playing audio file.

Do I need to really convert those (.mp3) files to .wav first before convert them again to .caf? Or using that command alone will do the work for me ?
Any additional info is welcome.

Comment: what is really wrong with the original `mp3` format?

Comment: For simultaneous playing, .mp3 will use software to play the audio file, just only one will be optimized and played with hardware on iOS. I intend to use this for sound effect, not music.